# WPF, C# - How to show a visual representation of my draggable UIElement underneath my cursor

Tags: c#, wpf

My situation:

I have a Canvas in which I hold some UIElements, these UIElements are constructed from custom UserControls. The UIElements can be Drag and Dropped to rearrange their position.
During my Drag and Drop operation, I would like to:

**1.** Show the UIElement which I am dragging, underneath my mouse cursor, with the cursor showing in the top left corner of the UIElement.

***OR***

**2.** Show a dotted border, transparent content, rectangle underneath my mouse cursor, with the cursor showing in the top left corner of the UIElement.

I was able to find a few posts, but they were very complex, a little too complex for me at the moment.
Is there anyone who knows how to do this, and would like to teach me?
Preferably with very clear to follow instructions.

Comment: You could create a custom cursor for your requirement.

Comment: Like this? https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MotionList  Check out some open source libraries to help with dragging: https://github.com/ButchersBoy/Dragablz and https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I will take a look at this a little later today.
I didn't think it would be possible to do with cursors?